# Tex to Lyx Error

Tags: lyx, import

I'm having two .tex files. For some reason one is easily imported into lyx without any problem. On the other hand, when I'm trying to import the second .tex file into lyx I'm getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while running:
tex2lyx -f "filename.tex" "filename.lyx"
```

Why is this happening? i can't see any difference between the two files.

I'm using Linux Mint 13. Both .tex files were created with Kile 2.1 and I'm trying to import them in Lyx 2.0.2

Comment: Stefanos: It is impossible from a community's perspective to address *why* there is a problem or "why [this is] happening". You should provide us with some evidence so we can investigate. How about showing us the two files?

Comment: You mean like the preamble?

Comment: There may be *many* things causing the import to fail, one of which is the preamble. It would be best if we can see the entire file, so those in the community with access to LyX can import it and see what the problem is. If that's not possible, then it would be difficult (perhaps impossible) to help.

Comment: If the two files are identical why do you try to import both? If there are not identical then why don't you see "any difference"?